# flink unable to pick s3 credentials from streaming job environment

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am running s3 test container and running job locally on my machine. I am really sorry i will not able to provide the minimum executable code because of codebase is quite huge and cannot paste here more details because of compliance issue. Any help would be much appreciated. This conf will get used by streaming file sink connector in the code.

```
    def startJob() = {
      val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
      env.setParallelism(1)
      val flinkConf = new Configuration()
      flinkConf.set(ConfigOptions.key("s3.access-key").stringType.defaultValue("s3_mock_access_key"), "s3_mock_access_key")
      flinkConf.set(ConfigOptions.key("s3.secret-key").stringType().defaultValue("s3_mock_secret_key"), "s3_mock_secret_key")
      flinkConf.set(ConfigOptions.key("s3.endpoint").stringType().defaultValue(s"http://$getS3MockHost:$getS3MockPort"), s"http://$getS3MockHost:$getS3MockPort")
      flinkConf.set(ConfigOptions.key("s3.path.style.access").defaultValue(true), true)
      env.configure(flinkConf)


      /**
       * This createExecutionGraph function contains large number of operator and we are passing env variable to it
       * for our local end to end testing
       */
       
      jobclient = StreamingJob
        .createExecutionGraph(env, Option(DYNAMIC_CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME), None, true)
        .executeAsync()
    }
```

Error getting
22:02:35,560 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Sink: sinkoperator (1/1)#0 (7026634c61d9bbeba29061c72487b9a4) switched from INITIALIZING to FAILED with failure cause: org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: doesBucketExist on test-pdx01: org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the S3 credentials from your job code, since the S3 filesystems are loaded as plugins during the startup of the Flink cluster. You can either use IAM or access keys, but in both cases you need to set it up in the `flink-conf.yaml` file. Details are at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#configure-access-credentials